# In Python i have fetched the rows in a text file by querying from oracle, i need to apply regex to rows and join the values using binary seperator

Tags: python, regex, split, row

In Python i have fetched the rows in a text file by querying from oracle, i need to apply regex to rows and join the values using seperator

Comment: You should write your file in a format that can be parsed by code, such as JSON or CSV.

Comment: After changing the file format, how to apply regex to this code. I am entirely new to python. i tried many regex split and sub all but i get syntax error issues.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use regex, string manipulation should suffice:

```
binary_sep = "\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF"
for row in records:
    new_row = "".join(row[1:])  # joins row to a string, starting from index 1
    new_row = new_row.replace("|", binary_sep)  # replaces each occurrance of "|" to binary_sep
    print(new_row)
```

This can also be done as a 1-liner:

```
new_row = "".join(row[1:]).replace("|", binary_sep)
```